# How do i import AWT?

Tags: java, awt

Im teaching myself java and the book i'm looking at just got around to explaining AWT.

here is my source code:

```
java.awt.*

class obj
{
    public static void main (String[]arg)
    {
        Point blank; 
        blank = new Point (3,4) ; 
        int x = blank.x ;
        System.out.prinln (x) ; 
    }
}
```

here is the error i get while trying to compile it:

```
obj.java:1: 'class' or 'interface' expected
java.awt.*
^
1 error
```

What did i do wrong? / whats going wrong here?

Comment: I highly recommend an IDE that can do this kind of thing automatically. Eclipse is a popular one that is free but there are of course many others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing `import` in the beginning:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `import` statement at the top like:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

You'll find this Sun tutorial useful: [`Using Package Members`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Don't concentrate on the fact that you are learning "awt". Remember your Java basics first and apply that knowledge to solve your problem.

the "awt" package is no different then any other package, you need an "import" statement.

Look at any other example in the book or forums to see how they are coded.

Comment: the problem was that there was no example. its sort of a crappy book.